# Drawing Application | Calculate similarity (Score) between UIImageView | iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimageview, quartz-2d

I am working on an app in which user can draw image using Quartz2D. I have to compare two images.

Right now I compare the pixel information between 1st image and the 2nd, by comparing RGB values of their respective pixels.
This solution, although works, but is not robust.

If somehow I can thicken the pixel widths in second, the chances to find intersection in images will increase.

Please help me to write a code to thicken pixel widths in an image.

Both images are Black and White.

[image]

Now I want to increase pixel like this and compare this image with what user have drawn.

[image]

Or suggest if there is a better way to compare 2 images.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my question. I am using [GPUImage Library](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) in ios. Now Using Image processing technique I am dilating my image to get desired result.

```
    GPUImageRGBErosionFilter *filter1 = [[GPUImageRGBErosionFilter alloc] initWithRadius:4];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [filter1 imageByFilteringImage:img];
```